# Drawing on OpenStreetMaps of Venezuela with Turistforeningen/leaflet-routing

Tags: javascript, plugins, routes, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm starting to use the plugin for a webapp that I'm building, this app uses openstreetmaps and is for Venezuela, but I'm having a problem because when I try to draw a route over the highways with bridges, only takes the street that are below of it or near of it. Can anyone help me?

The router function is the same that the plugin brings in the example:

```
OSM Router
                router = function(m1, m2, cb) {
                  var proxy = 'http://www2.turistforeningen.no/routing.php?url=';
                  var route = 'http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php&format=geojson&v=foot&fast=1&layer=mapnik';
                  var params = '&flat=' + m1.lat + '&flon=' + m1.lng + '&tlat=' + m2.lat + '&tlon=' + m2.lng;
                  $.getJSON(proxy + route + params, function(geojson, status) {
                    if (!geojson || !geojson.coordinates || geojson.coordinates.length === 0) {
                      if (typeof console.log === 'function') {
                            console.log('OSM router failed', geojson);
                      }
                      return cb(new Error());
                    }
                    return cb(null, L.GeoJSON.geometryToLayer(geojson));
                  });
                }
```

It works but as I said, with bridges does'nt.

[WithGoogleMaps](http://imageshack.com/a/img909/3783/rqfi67.png)

[WithOpenStreetsMaps](http://imageshack.com/a/img901/4350/zl2E6o.png)

Comment: Those Links are images where you can see what it does with bridges :/

Comment: Did you try one of the many other [online routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers)? The routing data of yournavigation is very (very) old. OSRM and GraphHopper are definitely a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done! The problem was that in `var route = 'http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php&format=geojson&v=foot&fast=1&layer=mapnik';`  the parameter **v** is the type of transportation and was set on **foot** and when I tried to draw a route over a bridge with a highways, it took only streets.

I changed that to `v=motorcar` and worked perfect! I found the answer in the doc of www.yournavigation.org, this problem is solved.

I'm still going to try with other online routers.